# How can I send an ArrayList as a stream to a nearby device using the Nearby Connections API in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, stream, bytearrayinputstream, google-nearby-connections

I am working on a server-client model using the Nearby Connections API, and I'm trying to transfer a large amount of data between the devices. I've already tried sending the data as bytes, but it didn't work well for large amounts of data. Now, I have an ArrayList containing 5000 records that I want to send as a stream to the nearby device, but I'm facing errors when I try to do this. I'm wondering if there is a way to send the 5000 records in chunks as byte format or if there is a way to send the entire ArrayList as a stream to the nearby device.

Here is the Code snipet to send arrayList:

```
 fun sendDataFromServer(list: ArrayList<PatientEntity>) {
        if (isHost) {
            val json = gson.toJson(list)
            Log.d(TAG, "Json : $json")
            val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(json.toByteArray())
            val payload = Payload.fromStream(inputStream)
            getClients().forEach { endpointId ->
                connectionsClient.sendPayload(endpointId, payload).addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Payload sent successfully: $payload")
                }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending payload: $payload", e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the Code snipet to recieve arrayList:

```
val inputStream =
                            payload.asStream()
                                ?.asInputStream() // Get the input stream from the payload
                        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                        val json = StringBuilder()
                        var line: String?
                        while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                            json.append(line)
                        }
                        val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<PatientEntity>>() {}.type
                        val list: ArrayList<PatientEntity> = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), type)
                        _patientList.value.addAll(list)
```

If I send less data arrayList so it works fine, but if try to send large arrayList it shows this error:

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

I would greatly appreciate your help if you know how to solve this issue. If you have a solution, please share it with me. Thank you in advance for your assistance.